# Cannot build iOS simulator in Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-ios

Cannot build iOS simulator in Flutter...

I tried to flutter clean and pod install... but still cannot running...

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
• Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
• CocoaPods version 1.11.3

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 13 Pro Max in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Xcode build done.                                           38.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **
Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/rg/v6d4v6m545949bhd3pv5555r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.cs5MRF/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirMRrlBc/temporary_xcresult_bundle
    fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't write to output file: /Users/pin-chientseng/Desktop/yomate/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core/grpc.framework/grpc.lipo (No space left on device)
    Command CreateUniversalBinary failed with a nonzero exit code
    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in dependency order
    /Users/pin-chientseng/Desktop/yomate/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the Runner editor. (in target 'Runner' from project 'Runner')
    /Users/pin-chientseng/Desktop/yomate/ios/Pods/Pods.xcodeproj: warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 15.2.99. (in target 'leveldb-library' from project 'Pods')
    Result bundle written to path:
        /var/folders/rg/v6d4v6m545949bhd3pv5555r0000gn/T/flutter_tools.cs5MRF/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirMRrlBc/temporary_xcresult_bundle
Uncategorized (Xcode): Command CreateUniversalBinary failed with a nonzero exit code

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 13 Pro Max.
```

Comment: In that output, it says `fatal error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/lipo: can't write to output file: /Users/pin-chientseng/Desktop/yomate/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/gRPC-Core/grpc.framework/grpc.lipo (No space left on device)` That is probably important.

Comment: @murgatroid99 so, it mean, the device is not enough HDD space?

Comment: @murgatroid99 I have other post, can I check it?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72223330/i-do-not-get-error-but-i-cannot-nunning-ios-simulator-when-i-debugging-in-flutt